# Android SharePreferrences General Questions

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I just have some basic questions about the way shared preferences work with Android:

1) Are the preference files part of the application itself, or are they stored elsewhere on the user's phone?

2) If I have created and modified preference files in the course of testing my app, will those preferences be the default settings for users, or do the users start with a clean slate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The preferences are stored on the user's phone, of course.

2) If you want defaults, you need to program them yourself, just setting the preferences in your emulator is not going to affect anybody installing your application.

Comment: So if I have a line of code "num = settings.getInt("num", 5);" then the end user will default to 5 the first time they run my app, regardless of what I've done to my own preference files?